# Animation unwanted delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
   var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        // Set navigation background
        if (scrollTop > 50) {
            $('.nav').animate({
                height: "90px",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)"
            });    
        } else {
            $('.nav').animate({
                height: "120px",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.0)"
            });    
        }
    });
```

```css
.nav {
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  position: fixed;
  }

.content {
  background-color: black;
  height: 4000px;
  width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Well I have this jQuery code and it has a gigantic unwanted delay on it, how can I fix this? Okey needed to add some more details, well this is the code who should animate my navigation bar but does it will like 6 seconds delay

Comment: You don't want it to animate at all?

Comment: Are you sure that the animation is starting?

Comment: Ha ha ha... Ofcourse I want to animate but it waites like 6 seconds and then it animates. Well I hope you understand I dont want those 6 seconds of waiting time, get it?

Comment: Yes after like 6 seconds It starts, but it sould directly start

Comment: Can I please get a fiddle?

Comment: Sure! wait a second

Comment: I added a Snippet, not the same thing you asked for, but I think its similiar

Comment: For me, the animation doesn't run at all, even when I scroll.

Comment: I made 1 mistake in the syntax, I forgot some brackets. Also I now see you can't scroll when it is in fullpage-mode, let me add something real quick

Comment: Great stackoverflow doesn't allow me to save changes to my snippet

Comment: Save it with jsfiddle

Comment: Okey I think I did something stupid but it s saved now, and it has the same issues I have in my own code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `stop()` before `animate`

```
$('.nav').stop().animate(...)
```

Comment: Great! solved my problem, Thank you!  actually kind of weird that it works, I only have 1 animation what I can think of in my qeue, but it works fine

Comment: Every time you scroll you trigger another animation, and animations run in queue unless you `stop()` them

Answer (score 0):

There must be a CSS transition delay holding it somewhere. Try inspecting the css of the element while the animation is happening and then trace that back to a css.

Comment: Weird I don't have any transitions in my css code, except for a button to have a smooth opacity change (transition: opacity 0.5s, top 0.2s; )

Comment: That rules out css, which would normally allow you to focus on finding the root of the problem on the javascript side. The transition delay, could potentially also be coming into any bootstrap or other css libraries you may have plugged in. That said ruling out CSS for animation troubles would be the first thing on my list, followed by delving into the JS side of things. In this case, the queued animations holding up the show.